# How to expand lists using slideToogle method jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 different headers which are also links to open 3 `ul` lists, please view html below.

After clicking one of the headers I want expend one of my list one by one not all of them, I made small loop using each method and this line

> $('h2.show-list'+$(this).attr('class')).slideToggle();

was written in the wrong way any idea, probably I am making small mistake any help appreciate

```
$('h2.show-list').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('gh'+i);
});

$('ul.categories').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('gh'+i);
});

$('h2.show-list').on('click',function(){            
    $('h2.show-list'+$(this).attr('class')).slideToggle();
    //$("div."+$(this).attr("class")).toggle("fast");
});
```

Please find the fiddle here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/przemeklewtak/rhrrtqpg/)

Comment: can you insert your HTML syntax or jsFiddle link ?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close with what you have, you had a typo with the class selector in your script, you were missing the s from show-litstS. Here's a solution that keeps the code pretty simple. It simply searches for the next occurance of a list from a clicked heading, and displays it.

```
$('h2').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

And [here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/rhrrtqpg/1/) to your fiddle.

Comment: of course if you post your html it will help produce a better solution

Comment: hi guys still can't sort out my problem i put full code as well here http://jsfiddle.net/przemeklewtak/rhrrtqpg/